# How to check server connection is available or not in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-networking

Testing of Network Connection can be done by following method:

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable() 
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But i don't know how to check the server connection.I had followed this method

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, long timeout) {
try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimetout(timeout);
    connection.connect();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your exceptions
    return false;
}
```

}

it doesn't works....Any Ideas Guys!!

Answer (score 2):

you can  check a server connection is available or not using `isReachable()`:

```
netAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(HOST_NAME);
boolean  reachable = address.isReachable(timeout);
```

and by using runtime:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("ping www.google.com");
```

Comment: Getting java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: which host name you are using? if you have web address like www.google.com  then try to use second option

Comment: selvan,u known what ping command done.these both option tell you host(server) is available or not

Comment: Gud..Its to Check for Server availability.fine Imran..If server was down then at that time what we have to do?

Comment: when  server connection is not available then do what u want?i do't known about your requirement.by this u only identify server connection is available or not as your question

Comment: Even if we give www.gogle.co.in instead of www.google.co.in,its working and give process id man?..Got twisted!!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9530/discussion-between-imrankhan-and-kalai-selvan-g)

Comment: ok but www.gogle.co.in also a web address that's why you are getting process id .try some other address and serach for Request timeout in response.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
 try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    connection.connect();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your exceptions
    return false;
}
```

}

and also add intent permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```